# Set floating point precision using rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

Is there a way to control the output precision in JSON generated using rapidjson?

For example:

```
writer.String("length");
writer.Double(1.0 / 3.0);
```

This generates something like:

```
{ length: 0.33333333 }
```

I'm sending a lot of values and only need two decimal places for several values.

Comment: It looks like this isn't possible. I've opened a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/issues/detail?id=67) for this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone stumbling onto this case, this method was added to rapidjson on Feb 11, 2016:

[`rapidjson::Writer::SetMaxDecimalPlaces(int maxDecimalPlaces)`](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/blob/48fbd8cd202ca54031fe799db2ad44ffa8e77c13/include/rapidjson/writer.h#L173)

The provided default Writer class is more complete than the other answer here, and should always be used, unless you have very specific needs.

Answer (score 7):

From sources

```
Writer& Double(double d)
{ 
   Prefix(kNumberType);
   WriteDouble(d);
   return *this; 
}

//! \todo Optimization with custom double-to-string converter.
void WriteDouble(double d) {
        char buffer[100];
#if _MSC_VER
    int ret = sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%g", d);
#else
    int ret = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%g", d);
#endif
    RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(ret >= 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < ret; i++)
         stream_.Put(buffer[i]);
}
```

> For the `g` conversion style conversion with style `e` or `f` will be
>   performed.
>
> `f`: Precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear after
>   the decimal point character. The default precision is `6`.

quotes from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

There is variant, to write new `Writer` class and write your own `Double` function realisation.

Simple example of last case

```
template<typename Stream>
class Writer : public rapidjson::Writer<Stream>
{
public:
   Writer(Stream& stream) : rapidjson::Writer<Stream>(stream)
   {
   }
   Writer& Double(double d)
   {
      this->Prefix(rapidjson::kNumberType);
      char buffer[100];
      int ret = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.2f", d);
      RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(ret >= 1);
      for (int i = 0; i < ret; ++i)
         this->stream_.Put(buffer[i]);
      return *this;
   }
};
```

usage like

```
int main()
{
   const std::string json =
      "{"
      "\"string\": 0.3221"
      "}";
   rapidjson::Document doc;
   doc.Parse<0>(json.c_str());

   rapidjson::FileStream fs(stdout);
   Writer<rapidjson::FileStream> writer(fs);
   doc.Accept(writer);
}
```

result: {"string":0.32}

Of course if you use `Writer` manually, you can writer function `Double` with precision parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's not natively possible then. I'm happy to add an overload into their API though, so will make one based on your suggestions.