# Rounding a double type with RapidJSON

Tags: floating-point, double, rounding, rapidjson

I'm using RapidJSON (https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson) to create quite big arrays (~ 5 MB) and a lot of the space is waste due to too accurate floating point numbers.
E.g.

```
StringBuffer s;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(s);
writer.StartObject();
writer.String("value");
writer.Double(1.0/3.0);
writer.EndObject();
```

This results in a json "{'value': 0.33333333333}" which is very annoying when I only need a few significant numbers.

I found a solution [Set floating point precision using rapidjson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104558/set-floating-point-precision-using-rapidjson) in this post, but it's already a few years old and outdated with the latest rapidjson build. Has anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rapidjson::Writer::SetMaxDecimalPlaces
http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_writer.html#aa7b6967dc237519e2a6d8b3939fb9634

```
writer.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(3);
writer.Double(1.0/3.0);
```

Comment: Note: the OP said he wanted to ROUND a double type, this method TRUNCATES

Answer (score 3):

Currently `Writer` always generate accurate string representation of floating point number, in the sense that parsing the output can restore the original value.

You may try the workaround on [this](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/issues/362). If you would like to request for providing this in RapidJSON, please comment there and we can further discuss.